# Move selected text to the right

Tags: visual-mode

Say I have a line `1234text5678`, where I have selected `text` in visual mode. I would like to have a command `<Shift>+`, that moves `text` to the right one character and selects `text` again. I.e. the result should be `12345text678`, and `text` being selected. From playing around, I got

```
xnoremap * dpgv=gv
```

but this selects `5tex` after the movement. How can it be adjusted? (I don't know if this is standard, but on German keyboards `<Shift>+` is the same as `*`.)

Then I would also like to create a similar command to move to the left, but probably I can figure that one out myself once I got the other version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Choice of Mapping

I personnally like to use `v_*` for searching the visually selected text, similar to what `n_*` does in normal mode for the word under the cursor. Using `v_*` for shifting a visual selection sideways is in conflict with [vim-visualstar](https://github.com/thinca/vim-visualstar) which I think could actually be the default behavior of vanilla vim.

Using `viwdp` or with an additional movement between `d` and `p` here is good enough for me.

[A](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Moving_lines_up_or_down) [typical](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired#unimpairedvim) [related](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-LineJuggler) [feature](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/bubbling-text/) request is shifting lines up and down. Greg Hurrell has produced a screencast how to do this ([youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X5IAdaN6IwM&list=PLwJS-G75vM7kFO-yUkyNphxSIdbi_1NKX&t=0s&index=65)). However, he
does not recommend it because:

> it encourages bad habits ... do not mash keys ... not the vim way

I agree and would say that repeat is an anti-pattern here.

If you want such behaviour and a direct key to press, consider also following plugins and their suggestions for mappings:

## Plugins and their Suggested Mappings

- [vim-move](https://github.com/matze/vim-move)

  The default mappings use the Alt-key as prefix which does not work in all circumstances:

  ```
  <A-k>   Move current line/selection up
  <A-j>   Move current line/selection down
  <A-h>   Move current character/selection left
  <A-l>   Move current character/selection right
  ```
- [vim-textmanip](https://github.com/t9md/vim-textmanip)

  ```
  xmap <C-j> <Plug>(textmanip-move-down)
  xmap <C-k> <Plug>(textmanip-move-up)
  xmap <C-h> <Plug>(textmanip-move-left)
  xmap <C-l> <Plug>(textmanip-move-right)
  ```

  The plugin [vim-tmux-navigator](https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator) uses the same set in normal mode to switch windows. This makes them a little bit inconsistent between modes.
- [vim-schlepp](https://github.com/zirrostig/vim-schlepp)

  ```
  vmap <unique> <up>    <Plug>SchleppUp
  vmap <unique> <down>  <Plug>SchleppDown
  vmap <unique> <left>  <Plug>SchleppLeft
  vmap <unique> <right> <Plug>SchleppRight
  ```

  Some may argue arrow keys are too far away from the homerow.

## Related Plugins

- If you want to shift list items, function arguments and similar, consider the plugins [sideways.vim](https://github.com/andrewradev/sideways.vim) and [vim-swap](https://github.com/machakann/vim-swap). Suggested mappings by the plugin author Andrew Radev are again:

  ```
  nnoremap <c-h> :SidewaysLeft<cr>
  nnoremap <c-l> :SidewaysRight<cr>
  ```

  vim-swap defines following two which I think are a quite good choice:

  ```
  nmap g< <Plug>(swap-prev)
  nmap g> <Plug>(swap-next)
  ```
- [**vim-exchange**](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-exchange) works differently by not shifting things around. I think this plugin fits better to the vim way. The mappings are

  ```
  call s:create_map('n', 'cx', '<Plug>(Exchange)')
  call s:create_map('x', 'X', '<Plug>(Exchange)')
  call s:create_map('n', 'cxx', '<Plug>(ExchangeLine)')
  ```

  and allows to use `.` if the target is addressed by the same mapping. E.g. swapping distant lines `cxx`, `<no>G` and then press `.` or `cxiw`, move and then `.`.

  I point the reader to the screencast by [Drew Neil](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/swapping-two-regions-of-text-with-exchange-vim/) to see it in action.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s two alternative solutions:

```
xnoremap * dp`[1v

xnoremap * dpgvlol
```

- `` `[ `` — Jump to start of pasted text
- `1v`  — reselect the same amount of text as the last visual operation, but starting from the current cursor position
- `gv`  — reselect the same visual area as last selection,
- `lol` — move visual selection right by moving the end one character to the right, and then jumping to the start and moving that one character to the right also.

Comment: Didn't know `[count]v`, thanks +1. But to be precise, it should be `last visual operation` instead of `last selection`, it's quite different.

Comment: Yes, I was sloppy there. I’ll correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
xnoremap * dp`[v`]
```

- `dp` shift right
- `` `[v`] `` select newly pasted content.

  - `` :h `[ `` mark start of last changed or yanked text.
  - `` :h `] `` mark end of last changed or yanked text.